# Not able to add css or iamge in thmeleaf spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

My CSS file is under resources/static/css then style.css
My image is under resources/static/image then home.png

Code for attching css

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title th:text="${title}"></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"> 
    </head>
```

```
    `<img th:src="@{/image/home.png}">`
```

for the image, it is showing me a 404 in the browser
and also CSS is not attached to the HTML page
I have included thyme leaf dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

I am facing this issue from a long time can some one help me?

Comment: Can you share your project structure as well so that we can see your src/main/resource folder structure?

Comment: please verify that, all your static files like css, images are present in static folder of your project directory structure